# Icefaces and Java, updating a value after partialSubmit

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, icefaces

I am using Java in combination with Tomcat 6 and Icefaces (1.8 I think).

I have 5  fields which accept decimal values, and then I have a 6th field right beside them (disabled) which is suppose to be the sum of the previous 5. I want the 6th field to automatically calculate the sum of the 5 and display it.

Here is the code that I used. It has 2 textboxes, 1 is an input, and the other is the output (I used an inputText for output cause it looks nicer).

```
<ice:panelGroup styleClass = "exampleBox selectionContainer">
    <ice:panelGrid columns = "2" styleClass = "verticalAlignTop">
        <ice:outputLabel for = "percent_O_can" value = "Other %:" style = "text_align: right"></ice:outputLabel> 
            <ice:inputText id="percent_O_can" size = "4" maxlength = "4" partialSubmit = "true" valueChangeListener = "#{new_Partner.can_total }" value="#{new_Partner.can_students[4]}" required="false">
        <f:validator validatorId="partners.decimalValidator" /> </ice:inputText> 
    </ice:panelGrid>
</ice:panelGroup>
<ice:message for = "percent_O_can" ></ice:message>

<ice:outputLabel for="can_total" value="Total Percentage" style="text-align: right;">
</ice:outputLabel>
<ice:panelGroup>
    <ice:inputText id="can_total" value="#{new_Partner.can_sum}" disabled="true" maxlength = "4">
    </ice:inputText>
<ice:message for="can_total" />
</ice:panelGroup>
```

Inside the value listener, I sum the 5 values of the array, and save the value (can_sum).

It works, but the only problem is the delay. Let's say I input the value for the 1st textbox, it refreshes after I unfocus, but the output value is 0. I then change the value of the second textbox, and after I unfocus, it submits, but the output value is now only the value of the 1st textbox. I change the value of the 3rd, and now the output is the sum of the 1st and 2nd. How can I eliminate this delay? If it is not too hard, can someone explain the priorities after which the attributes are ran?

Thank you.